# How to execute my function before my jquery submit until validation is correct

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, button

I want to call a JS function when a button is clicked and then continue execution of below `jquery` script

**Form :**

```
<form id="my_form">
  <button type="button" id="Bshift" onclick="return validation()">Clear</button>
</form>
```

**Pure JS Function:**

```
function validation(){
    // this has to be executed  first
    // do something here..
}
```

**Jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#Bshift').click(function(){
    // this has to be executed  second after everything in the validation is correct.
    // do something here that would be to insert to sql for example.
    }
});
```

I would like to know is how I execute my function before my jquery submit.

Comment: Why don't you "mix" both solutions... on jquery .click(function(){if(validation()){//...}else{//...}});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove onclick attribute from button tag and check validation inside click function

```
  <form id="my_form">
  <button type="button" id="Bshift">Clear</button>
</form>
```

Return true or false from `validation()` function

```
function validation(){

  return validationResult; // whether valid i.e. return true or if not valid return false

}
```

Then

```
  $('#Bshift').click(function(){
        var isValid=false;
        isValid = validation();
        // this has to be executed  second after everything in the validation is correct.
        if(isValid)
        {
         // do something here that would be to insert to sql for example.
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In the JS function, just return true if the validation succeeds:

```
function validation(){
  // this has to be executed  first
  // do something here..
  if (...) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

and in the jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#Bshift').click(function(){
    if (!validation()) {
      alert('Go away');
      return false;
    }

    // do your work
  }
});
```